# Lifecycle state management with Room live queries

Tags: android, android-room, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

I have a view with three states:

```
sealed class MainState(val movieList: List<Movie>) {
    class Loading(movies: List<Movie> = emptyList()) : MainState(movies)
    class Success(movies: List<Movie>) : MainState(movies)
    class Error(val throwable: Throwable, movies: List<Movie> = emptyList()) : MainState(movies)
}
```

These states are wrapped in a `MutableLiveData` and managed by a `ViewModel`:

```
class MovieListViewModel(private val movieRepo: MovieRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val stateLiveData = MutableLiveData<MainState>()
    .
    .
}
```

I want to integrate the query liveData to my state liveDate so that when query liveData is updated to movieList, state liveData updates to `Success(movieList)`. How can I acheive that?

Here's how my live query looks like:

```
@Dao
interface MovieDAO {
@Query("SELECT * FROM Movie")
   fun getAllMovies(): LiveData<List<Movie>>
}
```

Comment: `"I want to integrate the query Live data to my state live date."` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: A query liveData update to `movieList` result in state liveData update to `Success(movieList)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed RxJava2 support for Room, I will consider following:

```
val stateLiveData = MutableLiveData<MainState>()

dao().getAllMovies()
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .doOnSubscribe(() -> stateLiveData.value = Loading(emptyList()))
     .subscribeBy(
         onNext = { stateLiveData.value = Success(it) }
         onError { stateLiveData(it, emptyList()) }         
      )
```

of course you need to change the return type of the Room query to `Flowable<MainState>` or `Observable<MainState>`.

Comment: yes it seems to work. I don't have rxjava in my project though.

Comment: I'm just curious, you solution isn't lifecycle aware right? I have no experience with room rxjava support.

Comment: @saiedmomen I am assuming you are using ViewModel to handle your query. LiveData is a ifecycle aware object. For the RxJava subscription, you can dispose your subscription in `onCleared()` in ViewModel. The subscription method in my answer will return `Disposable` object. You can keep it as a member variable and dispose it when the `ViewModel` gets destroyed.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel#oncleared) is the documentation for `onCleared()`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with the use of [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData).

> LiveData subclass which may observe other LiveData objects and react
>   on OnChanged events from them.

The solution looks like this:

```
    val stateLiveData = MediatorLiveData<MainState>()

    init {
        stateLiveData.addSource(movieRepo.getAllMovies()) {
            stateLiveData.value = Success(it)
        }
    }
```

For more info please check this great [post](https://proandroiddev.com/mediatorlivedata-to-the-rescue-5d27645b9bc3)